# how to add click event on dynamically generate element jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

I was try to add click event on dynamical ID's on a table row. I have set row ID to each row of a table. Now I want to add click event to show a row (class="hidden")slidedown in toggle. Actually the table row will print through a loop using classic asp code.

```
<table id="bus-list" class="table table-bordered table-result">
                        <thead style="background-color: #FCA04E">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Bus Operator</th>
                                <th>Bus Type</th>
                                <th>Depart</th>
                                <th>Arrive</th>
                                <th>Duration</th>
                                <th>#</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="" class="display">
                                <td>
                                    <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
                                    <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">16:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">19:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">City Center</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>3Hours</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="hidden">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="buss-info">
                                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bus">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seat Type</th>
                                                    <th>Seats</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Lower Deck</td>
                                                    <td>31</td>
                                                    <td>650.00</td>
                                                    <td><button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="display">
                                <td>
                                    <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
                                    <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">16:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">19:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">City Center</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>3Hours</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="hidden">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="buss-info">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seat Type</th>
                                                    <th>Seats</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Lower Deck</td>
                                                    <td>31</td>
                                                    <td>650.00</td>
                                                    <td><button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="display">
                                <td>
                                    <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
                                    <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">16:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">19:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">City Center</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>3Hours</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="hidden">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="buss-info">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seat Type</th>
                                                    <th>Seats</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Lower Deck</td>
                                                    <td>31</td>
                                                    <td>650.00</td>
                                                    <td><button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="display">
                                <td>
                                    <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
                                    <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">16:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="time">19:10</span>
                                    <span class="station">City Center</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>3Hours</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="" class="hidden">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="buss-info">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Seat Type</th>
                                                    <th>Seats</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Lower Deck</td>
                                                    <td>31</td>
                                                    <td>650.00</td>
                                                    <td><button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Here is my jquery code to set row id:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var counter = 0;
   $("#bus-list tbody tr.hidden").each(function(){
        counter++;
        var newdivid = 'bus-more-div-' + counter;
        $(this).attr('id',newdivid);
    });

   var bCount = 0;

   $("#bus-list tbody tr.display td button[name='selectBus']").each(function(){

        bCount++;
        var newid = 'btn-viewMore-' + bCount;
        $(this).attr('id',newid);
        var dd =  $(this).attr('id');

        $('#btn-viewMore-' + bCount).on('click',function(){

        });

   });
```

I faild to add click event button to show hide the 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all that, you can just toggle the next tr sibling of the clicked button

```js
$('.btn-select').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('display hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="bus-list" class="table table-bordered table-result">
  <thead style="background-color: #FCA04E">
    <tr>
      <th>Bus Operator</th>
      <th>Bus Type</th>
      <th>Depart</th>
      <th>Arrive</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="" class="display">
      <td>
        <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
        <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
      </td>
      <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">16:10</span>
        <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">19:10</span>
        <span class="station">City Center</span>
      </td>
      <td>3Hours</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="hidden">
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="buss-info">
          <table class="table table-condensed table-bus">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Seat Type</th>
                <th>Seats</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Lower Deck</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>650.00</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="display">
      <td>
        <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
        <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
      </td>
      <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">16:10</span>
        <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">19:10</span>
        <span class="station">City Center</span>
      </td>
      <td>3Hours</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="hidden">
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="buss-info">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Seat Type</th>
                <th>Seats</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Lower Deck</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>650.00</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="display">
      <td>
        <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
        <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
      </td>
      <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">16:10</span>
        <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">19:10</span>
        <span class="station">City Center</span>
      </td>
      <td>3Hours</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="hidden">
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="buss-info">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Seat Type</th>
                <th>Seats</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Lower Deck</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>650.00</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="display">
      <td>
        <span class="operator">Greenline</span>
        <span class="bus-type">Volvo A/C Seater (2+2)</span>
      </td>
      <td>Volvo Sleeper</td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">16:10</span>
        <span class="station">Esplanade</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="time">19:10</span>
        <span class="station">City Center</span>
      </td>
      <td>3Hours</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="" name="selectBus" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-select">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="" class="hidden">
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="buss-info">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-bordered table-bus">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Seat Type</th>
                <th>Seats</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Lower Deck</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>650.00</td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" name="book" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Book Now</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```