# Add click event on dynamic html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I looked at this example [how to add click event on dynamically generate element jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068190/how-to-add-click-event-on-dynamically-generate-element-jquery)

It seemed close to my problem but I could not resolve it.

I want to be able to make items with javascript and add a click event handler on every row I add.
I have made this little snippet to illustrate my issue.

My Issue: The event is only added on the last row.

Here is my code.

```js
let items = [{name : "John"},{name : "Bob"},{name : "Joe"}];
let templatehtml = ` 
<label id="lblnumber{id}">{name}</label>
<button id="btnView{id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button> 
<br>
`;
   
items.forEach((item,index) => {
    item.index = index;
    AddUIitem(item,templatehtml);
});   

function AddUIitem(item,itemTemplate)
{
    itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{id}/g, item.index);
    itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, item.name);
    document.getElementById(`divContainer`).innerHTML += `${itemTemplate}`;

document.getElementById(`btnView${item.index}`).addEventListener('click',()=>{
        alert('Cliked ' + item.index);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer"></div>
```

```
  function AddUIitem(item,itemTemplate)
  {
      itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{id}/g, item.index);
      itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, item.name);
      document.getElementById(`divContainer`).innerHTML += `${itemTemplate}`;

      document.getElementById(`btnView${item.index}`).addEventListener('click',()=>{
          alert('Clicked ' + item.index);
      });
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is where the element is added. it is actually recreating the elements that have 
already been created un-linking the click events that have been set prior.

```
document.getElementById(`divContainer`).innerHTML += newelement;
```

So to solve this do not recreate the html of the element, instead add the new element to the existing container(element)

```
function AddUIitem(item,itemTemplate)
{

    itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{id}/g, item.index);
    itemTemplate = itemTemplate.replace(/{name}/g, item.name);

    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.innerHTML = itemTemplate;

    document.getElementById(`divContainer`).appendChild(card);

    document.getElementById(`btnView${item.index}`).addEventListener('click',()=>{
        alert('Clicked ' + item.index);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add your attribute values to class instead of id. and use "this" keyword